# Is there a way to mark a method as ensuring that T is not null?

Tags: c#, attributes, null

For example, if I have a method defined as...

```
T Create()
{
    T t = Factory.Create<T>();

    // ...

    Assert.IsNotNull(t, "Some message.");
    // -or-
    if (t == null) throw new Exception("...");
    // -or- anything that verifies that it is not null
}
```

...and I am calling that method from somewhere else...

```
void SomewhereElse()
{
    T t = Create();
    // >><<
}
```

...at `>><<`, I know (meaning me, the person who wrote this) that `t` is guaranteed to not be null. Is there a way (an attribute, perhaps, that I have not found) to mark a method as ensuring that a reference type that it returns or otherwise passes out (perhaps an `out` parameter) is guaranteed by internal logic to not be null?

I have to sheepishly admit that ReSharper is mostly why I care as it highlights anything it thinks could cause either `InvalidOperationException` or `NullReferenceException`. I figure either it's reading something that I can mark on my methods or it just knows that `Assert.IsNotNull`, simple boolean checks or a few other things will remove the chance of something being null and that it can remove the highlight.

Any thoughts? Am I just falling victim to oh-my-god-resharper-highlights-it-I-have-to-fix-it disease?

Comment: I too suffer from oh-my-god-resharper-highlights-it-I-have-to-fix-it disease. So you are not alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If ReSharper is why you care then you can mark the `Factory.Create<T>()` method with their `[NotNull]` attribute described in their [web help](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html)

Comment: I've been afraid of their web help, I think. This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I just have to contend with the fact that I'm never getting a reference to Resharper assemblies into our application :). Thank you!

Comment: @Shibumi - they actually show how to get around referencing their assemblies by cutting and pasting the definitions into your code. It's in the same link.

Comment: I was actually just coming back to amend that. I see they can detect the presence of the namespace and the attributes in your own code. I think I would still have a hard sell on that, though: "I'd like to add these extraneous attributes into our codebase so that my OCD for removing squiggly lines is satisfied." Thanks for your help, though; you zeroed in on exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how R# handles this, but the [Contract.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.assert.aspx) method may be what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could put a constraint on T to only allow `struct`.

You could use a language extension that allows you to make stronger definitions of pre/post conditions for your function (contract based programming), like [SpecSharp](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/), or [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx).  Code Contracts seems to leverage built-in systems from C# 4.0.  I have no experience with either - only heard of them.

Comment: The issue being it has to be something ReSharper recognizes.

Comment: @Shibumi: If you use one of the methods I suggested to solve the problem (which would give its own independent verification, and could guarantee this at compile time, relieving your code of runtime checks), you should definitely add configuration/pragmas to configure ReSharper to ignore them.  This looks like the right docs: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Analysis__Configuring_Solution-Wide_Analysis.html.  You should always examine and customize your warnings from any static analysis tools.

Comment: @Shibumi: But you're free to choose the solution best for you :)  It is often better to fully utilize the tools you already have than throw more technology at the problem.  Mike two's answer seems like a good one.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment that stuff like this (at least the 'how to check for __' stuff) should be standardized and that using common tools is a good way to go. +1 for that. Thanks! (The issue with disabling them with #pragma is that it will obfuscate places where I needed to see it. Using comments can look messy.)

Answer (score 0):

Could you cast T to an object then check if its null?

```
var o = (object)Factory.Create<T>();
if(o == null) throw new Exception();
```